# how to update sub attributes in html custom button input via javascript

Tags: javascript, getelementbyid

I want to update data-percent value on a radiobutton click before clicking the update button

html:

```
<input type="radio" name="percentage" value="50" onclick="changeVal(this.value)"> Happy 50 percent</input>

</br>

<input type="radio" name="percentage" value="75" onclick="changeVal(this.value)"> Happy 75 percent</input>
</br>

<button class="btn btn-danger my-btn" id = "myUpdateBtn" data-id="1" data-name="John" data-summary="John is Happy" data-percent="50" >Click to Update</button>
```

javascript:   my script function does not update button sub attribute value. please help.

```
changeVal(val){
 alert(val);
 document.getElementById("myUpdateBtn").value('data-price') = val;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

In order to access `data` attributes you have to do it like this:

```js
var val = document.getElementById('21').dataset.id;
var msg = document.getElementById('21').dataset.name;

alert(val); //Alert '21'
alert(msg); //Alert 'HiDiv'

document.getElementById('21').dataset.lastName = 'Rod'; //Create new data attribute

console.log(document.getElementById('21')); //View changes
```

```html
<div data-id='21' id='21' data-name = 'HiDiv'>

</div>
```

Comment: Don't forget that dataset uses camalCase for data attribute with dashes in them.